# How to do a query in Grafana with Elasticsearch as source datas?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, grafana

I am a beginner with Grafana and ElasticSearch. I added Elasticsearch source in grafana. Now, i would like do a query to show my datas.

An example of one data in Elasticsearch:

```
{

"_index": "shinken-2016.04.08",
"_type": "shinken-logs",
"_id": "AVP0GFeTmLuZ9eaw1Bjp",
"_score": ​1.0,
"_source": 

{
    "comment": "",
    "plugin_output": "",
    "attempt": ​0,
    "message": "[1460089115] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: shinken;hostname_test.com;MySQL - TCP;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;connect to address 10.11.12.13 and port 1234: No route to host",
    "logclass": ​3,
    "options": "",
    "state_type": "CRITICAL",
    "state": ​2,
    "host_name": "hostname_test.com",
    "@timestamp": "2016-04-08T04:18:35Z",
    "time": ​1460089115,
    "service_description": "MySQL - TCP",
    "logobject": ​2,
    "type": "SERVICE NOTIFICATION",
    "contact_name": "shinken",
    "command_name": "notify-service-by-email"
}
},
```

My goal it's to show in granafa the state number of one service (here it's MySQL - TCP) for each day (here 2016-04-08).

My question is: How to do a query in Grafana with Elasticsearch as source datas ?